# Cannot access localhost:8080 page when i try to run vuejs app using docker-compose

Tags: vue.js, npm, docker-compose, npx

Im facing an issue with docker-compose, when i try to run vuejs app inside a container.
First i build vuejs app using :

```
docker-compose docker-compose run node npm run build -- --mode=iso
```

so a folder ‘dist’ is created successfully in the project root, then i try to run server using this command :

```
docker-compose run e2e npm run serve
```

as an output of this command :

```
App running at:
  Local: http://localhost:8080/

 It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
 Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container’s external mapped port>/
 App is served in production mode.
 Note this is for preview or E2E testing only.
```

But when i try to access the page, i got : cannot access this page …

==> node service is dedicated to install all dependencies
==> e2e service is dedicated to run server and when it’s up i will run then e2e tests

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access `http://localhost:8080` ? If so it is mentioned that you need to access the container's mapped external port instead of 8080.

Comment: so how can i access container's mapped external port ??

Answer (score 0):

try to serve 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost in the run command of the vue server

That will make it accessible outside the network

Also please share the docker-compose.yml so I can make sure you are exposing the ports correctly

Comment: Daniel Sinai  when i try to run : " docker-compose run e2e npm run serve --host 0.0.0.0"  i got this  : 
ERROR in app
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/node/app/0.0.0.0' in '/home/node/app'
This is my docker-compose file : 
--------------------------------
**services:**
  **node:**
    image: node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app



  **e2e:**
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    working_dir: /home/node/app

Comment: Hi, you need to run the --host as the "entrypoint" of the vite container

Comment: I didn't understood, what do you mean by "entrypoint" of the vite container  ? cuz im little bit new to use docker-compose

Comment: Can you show share the docker-compose file?

Comment: ` _services_: -------------  **node**: image: node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine working_dir: /home/node/app environment: - NODE_ENV=production volumes: - ./:/home/node/app --------------------------------- **e2e**: image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal volumes: - ./:/home/node/app working_dir: /home/node/app `

Comment: Hi @DanielSinai, it would be useful to provide an actual example of the code in context.